# Change the price of a product in app purchase dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have some non-renewable subscriptions as products for in app purchase in my iTunes connect.
Something like this - Buy 1 GB, Buy 2 GB, Buy 3 GB etc

Now, if the user has bought 2 GB already, and he wishes to have 3GB, I need to adjust the price of 3GB, so that 2GB price is subtracted.

Can I change the price if any product like this?

Comment: You can do like Restore the previous Purchase and Buy the new Product.

Comment: How does that work?..can you help with that? thanks in advance

Comment: See my Answer and Let me know if you have any Querry.

Comment: I think you can't change price like this way.But You can change the price at any time in iTunes Connect.

Go to iTunes Connect -> Manage Your Applications

Select your application from the list.

To change application price click Rights and Pricing and change price .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can dynamically adjust the price of an In-app Purchase.

I'm assuming that your existing prices don't scale linearly (i.e., the price of your 3GB product is not equal to the sum of the prices of your 2GB and 1GB products).

This is far from an elegant solution, but you could work out ahead of time all possible combinations of product purchases and have separate products for them. For example, you'd have another product of "3GB after having already purchased 2GB", for the appropriate price. You could hide this product from the user unless they had first purchased the 2GB product.